# Correlation between matrix variables and its PCA scores

Tags: correlation, pca, dimensionality-reduction

Suppose a matrix $X$ and $T$ the score matrix obtained from a PCA decomposition of $X$. 
Denote as $x_i$ and $t_i$ the columns of $X$ and $T$ respectively.

Is there any reason for which $cor(x_i, t_1) > cor(x_i, t_j)$ ???

In other words, the variables of $X$ are more correlated with the score obtained from the first principal component?

Comment: Is this true for all $i$?

Comment: That's basically my question. Whatever hint or idea is welcome

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking: what does it mean if all variables are most strongly correlated with PC1?

Comment: I assume that this is not always true but I am wondering if it is more likely for a variable to be more correlated with PC1 than with the others PCs

Comment: "a variable" or "all variables"?

Comment: take $x_i$ a variable of $X$ . $\mathbb P(cor(x_i, t_1)>cor(x_i, t_2)) > \mathbb P(cor(x_i, t_1)<cor(x_i, t_2))$??

Comment: I do not expect all the variables to be more correlated with $t_1$. Maybe it's more likely for a variable to be correlated with $t_1$ than with $t_2$.

Comment: Ah, I see! Now I understood.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first PC is removing as much variance as possible from the data, I would expect that, in general, it would correlate more highly with the variables in the data set.

On a practical level, in my experience, the first PC is often quite general with high loadings on many variables while the later PCs are more specialized with high loadings on only a few variables.

I don't know of any proof of this and I don't think it's a mathematical requirement, it's just that it's usually the case for the sort of data where PC is usually applied.